# Python 2.7 matplotlib provides error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

provides the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xx/PycharmProjects/Udemy/Array_Processing.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/home/xx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 63, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to fix this? I assume the package isn't installed properly. I have mostly used Windows to python coding, but yeah, not sure what to do here.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You appear to be running a local (in your home directory) version of anaconda in preference to the standard system version of python: what version is it, and how exactly did you install it?

Comment: Correct, I installed anaconda(doing some data science work at the moment). I am on Ubuntu 14.04, latest Anaconda version(Installed yesterday). I installed it through their site and updated dependencies with `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already, try installing `matplotlib` through the `conda` command. The libraries for anaconda are kept separate from the ones installed for python by pip and such. I'd hazard to guess anaconda can't actually find the library. Another possibility may be that its using an incompatible library, in which case uninstall matplotlib and then use `conda` install.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that since I was running `anaconda`, the dependencies and packages need to be installed in the virtual environment by itself.

Therefore, `conda install matplotlib` is the solution.